# ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit: Custom toolbar button

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

There is HtmlEditorExtender Control in Ajax Control Toolkit and there is some problem with it :)

What if I want to add my own button in Toolbar? How it can be done?

For example, I want to add the button which will insert a code snippet (and hightlight it) or add the button which will call a dialog window in browser then make async image upload and then insert this image?

Comment: To add your own custom button see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348382/custom-button-in-htmleditorextender-control

Answer (score 0):

you don't have much option I guess in HtmlEditorExtender.
Alternatively, try using these:

- [FreetextBox](http://www.freetextbox.com/demos/)
- [obout ASP.NET HTML Editor](http://www.obout.com/editor_new/sample_ImageBrowse.aspx)